# What are the Rx Mini and Rx Jumbo rings?

Tags: terminology

Reading through the `ethtool` man page, I found the following:

```
   -G --set-ring
          Changes the rx/tx ring parameters of the specified network device.

       rx N   Changes the number of ring entries for the Rx ring.

       rx-mini N
              Changes the number of ring entries for the Rx Mini ring.

       rx-jumbo N
              Changes the number of ring entries for the Rx Jumbo ring.

       tx N   Changes the number of ring entries for the Tx ring.
```

I've searched online for some explanation of the difference/relation between these, without success.

Is there some official documentation I should be reading to understand these terms?  If not, could an expert here please explain them?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ring buffers on the NIC are important to handle bursts of incoming packets especially if there is some delay when the hardware interrupt handler schedules the packet receiving software interrupt (softirq). NIC ring buffer sizes vary per NIC vendor and NIC grade (that is, server or desktop). By increasing the Rx/Tx ring buffer size as shown below, you can decrease the probability of discarding packets in the NIC during a scheduling delay. The tool used to change ring buffer settings is the Linux utility, ethtool.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQPD3_2.6.0/com.ibm.wllm.doc/nicringbuffers.html

{edit}

*Mini* is for undersized frames, *jumbo* for oversized. The exact definitions may be vendor and configuration specific, but usually undersized means smaller than 60 octets (64 bytes incl FCS) and oversized larger than 1514 octets (1518 incl FCS, 1522 incl FCS and 802.1Q tag).

Comment: Thanks, but I understand the basic concept of ring buffers.  What I don’t see explained is what the rx-mini and rx-jumbo rings are.

Comment: @Wildcard I've added that to the answer.